# Meaning of "equal measures"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could some explain the meaning of "equal measures"? I thought that "equal" here plays the role of adjective and "measures" plays a plural noun role (in the meaning of "amount")

> Fif's dragged out lar in "popular" was equal measures cocky,
> leaned-back, and ominously aggressive, punctuated by a simple fact:
> He'll hit you; he's been through worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you've got it. Equal amounts. "measure" is a somewhat rare/outdated noun short for "an amount measured out".

We also have the adverbial phrase "in equal measure" (not plural):

> He was cocky, leaned-back, and aggressive in equal measure.